# Buddypress Activity search with OR query instead of AND

Tags: search, buddypress

I have a profile field with checkboxes where users can check their "interests". I'd like to customize the activity feed by scoping it down with a search string including the users interests. Following the search term method here (the example with "nap"):
http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-customize-the-buddypress-activity-loop/

I have this at the top of activity-loop.php:

```
<?php
  $activity_search_terms = "&search_terms=";
  if ( $interests = xprofile_get_field_data( 'Interests', bp_loggedin_user_id() ) ) {
    foreach ( $interests as $interest ) {
      $activity_search_terms .= strtolower($interest) . "+";
    }
  }
?>

<?php if ( bp_has_activities( bp_ajax_querystring( 'activity' ) . rtrim($activity_search_terms, '+') ) ) : ?>
```

This would work perfectly if the activity search were using an OR query instead of an AND query. Right now if a user clicks "yoga" and "crossfit" as interests, the activity feed is only posts with BOTH those terms instead of EITHER.

I installed Relevanssi and have it set to OR query, but it doesn't appear to apply to the activity search. Is there a way to force an OR query for `bp_has_activities`?

Using WP 4.1 and BP 2.1.1

**UPDATE:**
I have it working via modifying BuddyPress `bp-activity\bp-activity-classes.php` around L.346 to write a LIKE statement for each search term. If you can tell me how to achieve the same thing in a plugin (without having to avoid `$wpdb->prepare`), the bounty is yours!

```
// Searching
if ( $search_terms ) {
  $search_terms_array = explode(' ', $search_terms);
  // WAS: $search_terms_like = '%' . bp_esc_like( $search_terms ) . '%';

  $search_terms_like = '';
  foreach( $search_terms_array as $term)
    $search_terms_like .= 'a.content LIKE \'%' . bp_esc_like( $term ) . '%\' OR ';
  $where_conditions['search_sql'] = rtrim($search_terms_like, ' OR ');
  // WAS: $where_conditions['search_sql'] = $wpdb->prepare( 'a.content LIKE %s', $search_terms_like);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously had a solution which edited core files. Here's a solution you can drop into functions.php or build a plugin with:

```
// Customize activity filters
add_filter( 'bp_activity_get_where_conditions', 'my_activity_filters', 1, 1 );
function my_activity_filters($search) {

  $search_terms = explode( "%", $search["search_sql"] )[1];
  $search_terms_array = explode(' ', $search_terms);
  $search_terms_like = '';

  if( !empty( $search_terms_array ) ) {           // Searching for something specific
    foreach( $search_terms_array as $term)
      $search_terms_like .= 'a.content LIKE \'%' . bp_esc_like( $term ) . '%\' OR ';
    $my_search = rtrim($search_terms_like, ' OR ');
  } #else if(  ) {                       // Not searching for something specific, but user has interests, show those

  #} else {                              // Not searching for something specific, and user has no interests, show everything

  #}

  $search["search_sql"] = $my_search;

  return $search;

  #echo "<hr>";
  #echo "<strong>Search terms:</strong> $search_terms<br><br>";
  #echo "<strong>New search terms:</strong> $my_search<br><br>";
  #echo "<hr>";
}
```

Not production ready by any means but uncomment the echos and read the comments and you'll be able to get what you need.

Comment: Can I seriously not award myself the bounty? No one else answered in a specific enough manner.

Comment: You shouldn't modify core files

Comment: Agreed. Posted a solution that doesn't edit core files.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this filter:

```
$where_conditions = apply_filters( 'bp_activity_get_where_conditions', $where_conditions, $r, $select_sql, $from_sql, $join_sql );
```

In \buddypress\bp-activity\bp-activity-classes.php ~L. 418

Comment: I saw around that code before, and figured swapping `AND` for `OR` on line 421 would work. That didn't do what I thought it would. I'm not sure what to do with the filter you mentioned. Would you mind telling me how I could work that into the code in the question (in activity-loop.php)?

Comment: L. 421 is for ALL the where conditions!  Use the filter hook. Make your adjustments to $where_conditions for Search and return it. Use var_dump on the variables so you can see what they are. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter

Comment: I'm a big noob, and don't really know how to add that filter. The var_dump is showing that the change needs to be in `search_sql`. It's currently `[search_sql] => a.content LIKE '%outdoors yoga %'` and needs to be `[search_sql] => a.content LIKE '%outdoors%' OR LIKE '%yoga%'`.

Comment: I've got it working via modifying `buddypress\bp-activity\bp-activity-classes.php` around L.346. If you can tell me how to achieve the same thing in a plugin, I'll place a 50 bounty :)